# Summary Data Appears in SSRS 2008R2 CSV Export

Tags: csv, reporting-services

I have prepared a very simple report in SSRS 2008R2. The body of the report consists of one datasource organized into a table of detail records. I have added a summary record by adding group totals after the details to display the sums  for the last 5 columns.

When exporting the report to a .csv file, the data from the body of the report displays correctly, however, the 5 columns of summary data are appended to the end of each data record.

The user has requested to include the summary record in the report but to exclude the additional columns that have been appended to the data records. The other limitation they have imposed is that no other textboxes appear in the .csv file export. They only want to see the detail records with one header record at the top. The report needs to be exported as a .csv file because it exceeds the number of records which Excel can handle.

So far my research has reminded me that exporting a .csv file from SSRS exports only the data and strips out all formating, therefore, the summary data is associated with each data record.

Is anyone aware of a way to include the group totals on the report but exclude the summary data when exported to a .csv file?

Comment: Is the report returning more than 65535 rows, or more than 1048576 rows?

Comment: I just changed it from CSV to Excel

Answer (score 4):

For each data element you want to exclude:

1. Open the properties menu for the `TextBox` with <kbd>F4</kbd>
2. Set the `DataElementOutput` property to `NoOutput`

   [image: screenshot]