# SSRS 2012 and CSV export

Tags: csv, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2012 trying to do the following:

Some columns should only be visible on user request, using a combo box. Visibility of the columns dependes on the selected columns on the combo. This seems to work fine!

When I export the output in any format different of .csv these columns remain invisible. But when exporting to .csv invisible coulmns are shown.

I found this:

```
=iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="CSV", True, False)
```

This should be placed in the "Hidden" property of the column I'm trying to hide. But it doesn't work and when I write the expression RenderFormat is not an option as auto-complete.

Sorry for my clumsy english and thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSV (and XML) export from SSRS is treated very differently than most export formats. These two are considered data renderers, not page renderers, and are generally written to get at the data underlying the report, disregarding layout options. Part of this is that field visibility isn't handled the same way. I don't know if it's a bug or intentional design, but .CSV apparently [doesn't honor visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105220/ssrs-conditionally-hiding-columns-based-on-parameter-values-csv-export-ignore) set in expressions. One suggested work around is to conditionally set the value to `null` in the underlying dataset. (This could be based on a parameter.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've read that it does honor Hidden set in expressions. At least in SSRS 2008. I'd appreciate if someone could check this for me.

Comment: Not sure if you looked at the Stack Overflow question I linked to, but others are seeing the same thing that you are. Once the visibility is any more complicated than "True" or "False" is stops working for .CSV.

Comment: @JamieF, That question is a few years old, and it may be the difference between 2008 and 2008 R2. I have successfully used expressions in SSRS 2008 R2 to handle visibility on export. The problem may lie somewhere else.

Comment: @dev_etter, with .CSV export? I'll work up a repro in the next few hours.

Comment: @JamieF, I stand corrected - I tried to whip up a sample and I couldn't (I swore I got this to work a few months ago). I agree with your approach to using a parameter to set values to null, or even to set the column visibility to false based on the value of that parameter.

Comment: @JamieF, there is a native way to do this as well

Comment: @KyleMit Yep, you're right. The DataElementOutput doesn't support a formula, so it can't be dynamically set to be included or not depending on parameters or something else in the report. But I don't think this OP needed that...

Answer (score 2):

There is a native way to hide data elements sent to CSV by using `DataElementOutput=NoOutput`

1. Open the properties menu (<kbd>F4</kbd>) for the `TextBox`
2. Set the `DataElementOutput` property to `NoOutput`

   [image: screenshot]

#### Further Explanation

When SSRS has to render a chart, it has a couple of decisions to make.  If you spent a lot of time doing some cool formatting, it will try to preserve that when going to PDF because PDF documents are full of rich formatting.  For example, if you set the margins of the report, a PDF should care, but a CSV has no way to even hold that information (nor should it).

As such, there are [**different rendering engines** used by SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239307.aspx):

[image: Render Engines]

Each of these has their own process.  The data exports, for example, will only pull information from datafields.  For example, a data field is welcome to have several layers of headers, the names of which  may or may not use [**CLS-compliant identifiers**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27535419/1366033), so it's safer to extract that information directly from the textbox name itself.

The TextBox containing the data can be used to set other data export properties as well.

In this instance, you can remove a particular data field by using the [**DataElementOutput**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.rdlobjectmodel.chartdatapoint.dataelementoutput.aspx) which:

> Indicates whether the data point should appear in a data rendering.

#### Further Reading

- [SSRS: Conditionally hiding columns based on parameter values - CSV export ignores](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2105220/1366033)
- [Summary Data Appears in SSRS 2008R2 CSV Export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8122016/1366033)
- [Hide/Show Items Dependant On Export Format (SSRS)](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/)