# SSRS - Columns Download to .CSV Despite Visibility Status

Tags: excel, csv, reporting-services

I have a Reporting Services 2012 table that hides certain columns based on parameter choices, since some choices will cause the dataset to exclude certain columns when run.  So, a column such as PassportID would have a hiding criteria expression such as:

```
=IIF(Parameters!TransitMode.Value = "bus"
   OR Parameters!TransitMode.Value = "train",True,False)
```

The columns are indeed hidden when the report is rendered, and when it is downloaded to Excel.  The problem is that I need to download it to a .CSV file.  The .CSV downloader in SSRS does not have a layout renderer that can preserve the hiding criteria the way Excel can.

I looked at the [DataElementOutput](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2007/02/07/reporting-services-why-aren-t-all-my-report-columns-exporting-to-csv-and-or-xml.aspx) property, but changing this from the "Auto" default only appears to be give the options of downloading or excluding unconditionally, rather than based on column visibility in the rendering.

Is there a way to exclude the entire rendered column from the downloaded .CSV?

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer is to set the displayed value to a formula, using the Render format function. If the Render format is CSV, then set the "Displayed value" to be an empty string. The field will still be exported, but won't contain data.

That is, set the value of the textbox to something like:

```
 =iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="CSV", "", Fields!MyDataField.Value)
```

A little bit more info:
[SSRS 2012 and CSV export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015873/ssrs-2012-and-csv-export/13016088#13016088)

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the entire column to be excluded.  This doesn't appear to be possible with a single tablix in SSRS currently.

Comment: Yep, and I doubt this will be added anytime soon. CSV and XML output are designed to be stable output formats to use to interface business systems, such as supplying data to an SSIS package.

Answer (score 1):

Change the DataElementOutput from Auto to NoOutput.

DataElementOutput controls whether or not the data is included in the export.  Column headers are already excluded by CSV and names of columns for CSV are derived from the name of the textbox for a data element.  Visibility properties are not considered in the CSV export since visibility is a formatting feature.

Comment: I don't see how this would achieve the desired result.  I'm trying to make appearance in the downloaded .csv be driven by parameter choice.  "NoOutput" is unconditional.  In my example, if the user chose value "air" for the parameter, the column would appear in the rendered report, but be missing from the .csv, where it should also be included.

Comment: True.  The NoOutput column doesn't support expressions, so it would not be possible to toggle this on demand.  Jamie F's solution would prevent you from displaying data that you don't want, but it won't prevent the column from rendering.